# git merge --ff creates merge commit

Tags: git, gitlab, fast-forward

I'm trying fast forward develop branch to the main as

```
git checkout main
git merge --ff develop
git push
```

but that for some reason creates merge commit which introduces a new hash

Then I have did that:

```
git merge --verbose --ff-only develop
```

which ended up with

```
fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.
```

Regular `--ff` came up as

```
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 pom.xml                         | 2 +-
 src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml | 2 +-
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
```

Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Can you show us the output of the `git merge` run? I do not think that a merge is created there, if successful.... _perhaps_ you are trying to merge a branch that has a merge at the tip, so you end up with a merge at the tip.

Comment: @eftshift0 OP updated with more info

Comment: Not much to add. The message sais it all. Can't ff.... that happens because where you are standing, you have diverged from the branch you are trying to merge. A ff only happens if you are standing on an ancestor of the branch you are trying to merge.

Comment: Was reading the documentation.... so --ff alows for a merge commit to happen if a ff is not possible....  it is a default option, by the way. --ff-only breaks because... well, I explained already.

Comment: @eftshift0 so there is no way to fix it? or wipe out the main branch (it has only obsolete not working code anyway)

Comment: If what you want is a ff from the point you are, rhen sure, can't be done. But why do you want to avoid it in the first place?

Comment: @eftshift0 it is for CICD. Main should to use artifact created in develop based on the commit hash so it requires to have it fast-forward merged.

Comment: if that is the case, and it has always worked with ff, I would ask 2 things: 1 - why did it diverge? There has to be a commit over there in the branch that you are working with that is busting the ff attempt. 2 - Why do you try to merge in the first place? Have you considered alternatives like checking out the upstream branch straight instead of trying to merge some local branch? Given that you are using ff (and expect it to succeed), why not checkout the other branch instead?

Comment: @eftshift0 I'm checking out only my feature (local) branch and then CICD will picks and merge to develop and there will create an artifact which should to be used after -ff to the main

Comment: I'm not following.... it's simple: The merge with `ff` is failing _because there is at least a commit in the branch that you are on that is **not** in the history of the branch you are trying to merge_.. and I think from your comments that there shouldn't be such. Do you know what commit that is? Do you know _why_ it is there? If the answer to the first question is _"I don't know"_ then try to find out. git log: `git log ^the-other-branch HEAD` (notice the `^` in the first branch). That should be empty for a ff to work. If it's not empty then something _unexpected_ will pop up.

Comment: To make a long story short... In the merge where you are expecting an FF to **always** work (because it never diverges, I would assume), instead of merging, do a `git reset --hard` indicating the other branch. That will _never_ fail and you will end up at exactly the same commit the other branch is on.... no checks for divergence.

Comment: @eftshift0 OK, so what steps should I take? Go to the main branch and do `git reset --hard develop` from there?

Comment: Of you need to set master where develop is, then _yes_.

Comment: OK, that did the job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ff` only works if you are standing on an ancestor of the branch you are trying to merge:

```
A <- B <- C <- (master)
          ^
           \ D <- E <- F <- (develop)

git checkout master
git merge --ff-only develop
```

That would be ok (because `master` is on an ancestor of `develop`)

```
A <- B <- C <- G <- (master)
          ^
           \ D <- E <- F <- (develop)

git checkout master
git merge --ff-only develop
```

This would *not* work because now `master` is not on an ancestor of `develop`.

So..... why is `G` there? I would not be able to know. You should be able to list that (or those) commit with this to be able to see what they are about:

```
git log ^develop master
```

Now.... if you *always* intend to have `master` on top of `develop`, there's more than one way to do it. The way you are attempting (`git merge --ff-only`) works if you are on an ancestor..... but if you always want it to work regardless of anything that you have committed in `master`(you don't care losing it if there's something at all), then you can do:

```
git checkout develop
git branch -f master # set master where we are right now
git checkout master
```

Or

```
git checkout master
git reset --force develop
```

The first approach looks more efficient because the working tree is only being adjusted once whereas in the second it is twice (unless you are in master to start with).